# API metering and analytics using API connect on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I provisioned API connect in Bluemix using various plans. None of the plans gives me the ability to add custom analytics, setting up developer portal and api metering.

The videos available on youtube shows the above functionality. Am I missing something or is it the case that these features are available for on-prem installation of API connect and not with API connect on Bluemix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you sign up for the Lite, Professional, or Enterprise level plans, you should have access to what you saw in the videos.

Analytics are viewable via the Catalog where your APIs are published. You'll see a tab specifically for this and you can customize the dashboards there.

The developer portal must be enabled via Catalog settings. Here's more information on how to accomplish that: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.devportal.doc/tapim_tutorial_using_ADP.html